# Replace partial string with special characters in

Tags: c#

I want to replace: `reference1\":\" null\"` with `reference1\": null`

Example part of string to edit:

```
{\"reference1\":\"null\",\"secondarything\":
```

I've tried literal:

```
strValue = strValue.Replace(@reference1\":\" null\","reference1\": null");
```

I have quotes elsewhere I which to keep. It's the combination of quotation and backslash that has stumped me here.

Comment: Actually, having formatted your post, it's clear that there are backslashes which were hidden in the first edit..

Comment: This looks like json, and if it is, something is wrong and there are better ways to do this

Comment: It is some json, this is some test data to find a bug/maybe incorrect feedback. Not perfect but the above has meant I've not found the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes using `\` -

```
strValue = strValue.Replace("reference1\":\"null\"" , "reference1\": null");
```

### EDIT 1 :

If your string already contains `\`, then escape them with additional `\`, so now the code looks like -

```
strValue = strValue.Replace("reference1\\\":\\\"null\\\"", "reference1\\\": null");
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use a normal string, and add a backslash before each `"` or `\` :

```
strValue.Replace("reference1\\\":\\\" null\\\"", "reference1\\\": null")
```

Or use a verbatim string, and double up the `"`'s:

```
strValue.Replace(@"reference1\"":\"" null\""", @"reference1\"": null")
```

---

That said, this looks like an XY problem: that string looks awfully like JSON, and trying to string manipulation on JSON is normally a bad idea. Using a json parser like Json.net is probably a better route towards whatever problem you're trying to solve.